# Javascript for loop until - multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am using javascript, using regex to scrape images from html code.

I want the loop to run either until the script finds no more images or until it reaches 12.

I'm trying the following but not working:

```
var imgs = d.getElementsByTagName('img'), found = [];
for(var i=0,img; ((img = imgs[i]) || ( $i < 13)); i++)
```

Is this possible? Am I on the right lines?

Quite new to javascript but trying!

Comment: You may have been down voted because you didn't describe what specifically isn't working for you. IMO, there's enough code here with visible errors to be able to give an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use `&&` instead of `||`. Also, `$i` should be `i`.

```
for(var i=0, img; (img = imgs[i]) && (i < 12); i++)
     found.push(img);
```

Comment: Aaahhhh - i was actually using && and the $i is me being stuck in php mode! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you want `found` to contain those first 12:

```
var imgs = d.getElementsByTagName('img');
var found = [].slice.call(imgs, 0, 12);
```

You have to use `[].slice.call(imgs, ...)` instead of `imgs.slice()` because `imgs` is only a pseudo-array, and not a real array.

An alternative to writing `[].slice` is `Array.prototype.slice`.

If you want to do something else inside the loop, just use the array created above to ensure that you only work on the first 12 images:

```
for (var i = 0, n = found.length; i < n; ++i) {
    // do something with found[i];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `.slice` won't work that way in IE8 and lower since it's not a native object.

Comment: @user1689607 you mean the function doesn't exist?

Comment: No, I mean IE rejects anything as the calling context of its `Array.prototype` methods that isn't a native JavaScript object. Since `HTMLCollection` *(or `NodeList` or whatever)* is a host object, IE doesn't like it.

Comment: @user1689607 damned IE - the whole point of the standard `Array` function implementations is that they're supposed to be able to be called on array-like objects.

Comment: Well, at least they're mending their ways. :) But you're right, the Array methods are supposed to be generic according to ES5. I don't know how it was worded in ES3.

Comment: @user1689607 the MDN site implies that the ES3 implementation was supposed to be generic too - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Well then they really *did* mess up.

Answer (score 3):

I personally hate when people do assignment in the condition clause of a `for` loop, since it looks like someone mistook an assignment (`=`) for a comparison (`===` or `==`). Better to do the logic elsewhere.

```
var imgs = d.getElementsByTagName('img'), 
    found = [],
    i,
    imgsLength = imgs.length,
    max = imgsLength > 13 ? 13 : imgsLength;
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    found.push(imgs[i]);
}
```

or

```
var imgs = d.getElementsByTagName('img'), 
    found = [],
    i,
    imgsLength = imgs.length;
for (i = 0; i < 13 && i < imgsLength; i++) {
    found.push(imgs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Loop with multiple statements

```
let products= [...]
let users= [...]

for(let i=0,userParam = null, productParam=null; i<products.length; i++, userParam=products[i], productParam=products[i]){

....

}
```